# VRRP IP Mcast - how does intermediate switch handle

Tags: networking, router, vrrp

I have two routers A and B. Both have VRRP configured for Lan 0, Lan1 and Lan 2. Both routers are connected to a common router. When VRRP IP Multicast packet sent from Lan 0, Lan1 and Lan 2, what does next hop do? Does it send Lan 0 VRRP adv to both Lan1 and Lan2? Would that not confuse vrrp service?

Comment: The VRRP multicast is restricted to a single link (VLAN/network), and will not cross a router.

Comment: Thanks Ron, my question is within the next hop, does Lan0 vrrp adv sent to Lan0/1/2 of another router?

Comment: My point is that VRRP does not hop. It is confined to the network on which it is originated. A router will not send it to another network.

Comment: Thanks again Ron, if I read your comment correctly, Router A lan0 VRRP adv is for a specific interface , say 10.0.100.0/24 so its sent to same subnet interface which is Lan 0 of router B.

Comment: The routers must be connected on that network, and the multicast will travel on that network between the routers. Remember that FHRPs, like VRRP, are to fool the hosts on that network as to the gateway on that network.